# Docker google container registry

Tags: docker, google-container-registry

I am trying to push an image using docker - not gcloud* - to the google container registry. I have credentials and I have used the Json auth option.

I log into the registry by typing the following command

> docker login -u _json_key -p "$(cat filekey.sjon)" https://us.gcr.io/myregistry

It returns with

> Log in succeeded

After this I use

Docker push

It begins pushing and then returns with

> denied Unable to access the repository, please check that you have permission to access it

Is it possible to use docker to push to google container registry without gcloud?

Answer (score 1):

To enable publishing from docker without the gcloud sdk, it is necessary to navagate to the Iam & admin => serviceaccounts page in the google console. There you can generate the keys and services. As apposed to generating the credentials on the google API credentials page.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this should work.  Can you reach out via gcr-contact@google.com and share additional details so the team can help track down what's going on?

EDIT: I take that back, what happens if you remove "myregistry" from the login?

Comment: I tried it without the myregistry and it says log in succeeded as well

Comment: The google team was very helpful and responded quickly but we were able to solve the issue ourselves